# How do I read a variable created during the flow and set it as a header in the HTTP request component?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave, mule4

I have been struggling for access a variable that was defined during the flow and now I need to use it as part of authorization header in the HTTP request component. So far I have tried the following ways:

```
"Bearer " ++ vars.myVar
"Bearer " ++ #[vars.myVar]
"Bearer #[vars.myVar]"
```

None of them works since I am able to see the raw input in the console logs which reads as follow:

```
POST /webserviceurl HTTP/1.1
accept: application/json
authorization: "Bearer " ++ #[vars.myVar]
x-correlation-id: 06386edf-93a9-4d38-a117-d971f9eb7c11
Host: test.salesforce.com:443
User-Agent: AHC/1.0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
```

Here is the definition for the HTTP request config:

```
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_configuration" doc:name="HTTP Request configuration" doc:id="ad136a30-3119-44d1-ac13-8163214df28b" >
    <http:request-connection protocol="HTTPS" host="${SalesforceBaseUrl}" port="443" >      
    </http:request-connection>
    <http:default-headers >
        <http:default-header key="content-type" value="application/json" />
        <http:default-header key="accept" value="application/json" />
        <http:default-header key="Authorization" value='"Bearer " ++ #[vars.myVar]' />
    </http:default-headers>
</http:request-config>
```

What I am missing here? Which one is the right way to access a variable there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your value can't be mixed, it's either an expression or a literal string (except in the logger).

So in this case it should be:

```
#["Bearer " ++ vars.myVar]
```